# MatPaginator not working in dynamically generated table.

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am generating data Dynamically, and displaying it in Data Table, but I`m unable to link MatPaginator with the data table. Data is getting displayed in the table. Following is the sample code snippet (also attaching it ):

```
  sCollectionList = null;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<object>(this.sCollectionList);
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];

  // SCollectionService Holds my custom HTTP methods //
  constructor(private stColServ: SCollectionService) {
  }


// Calling it when a Button from UI is clicked //
  submitFilter() {

    // stFilter is a valid objet which is getting passed to my custom post request// 
    this.stColServ.stationFilter(this.stFilter).subscribe(
      data => {
      this.sCollectionList = data;

      this.displayedColumns = ['System Data' , 'Product Identifer' , 'Collected Date' , 'No Stations ?' , 'No Smnp ?', 'Export'];
this.dataSource.data = this.sCollectionList;

//      this.streamOfDataUpdates.subscribe(newData => this.dataSource.data = this.sCollectionList);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      },
    );

  }


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  /**
   * Set the paginator after the view init since this component will
   * be able to query its view for the initialized paginator.
   */
 ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

I am Able to see the paginator on the UI, but it is totally unresponsive. Following is my sample HTML MatTable code,  which displays data in the table:

```
<div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="example-container mat-elevation-z8 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

            <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="System Data"> 
            <mat-header-cell fxFlex="200px"
                *matHeaderCellDef> System Data </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell
                *matCellDef="let station"> <textarea readonly rows="8"
                wrap='off' show-tail> {{station['collectedData']}}</textarea> </mat-cell> </ng-container> 
            <ng-container
                matColumnDef="Product Identifer"> <mat-header-cell
                *matHeaderCellDef>Product Identifer</mat-header-cell> <mat-cell
                *matCellDef="let station"> {{station.productIdentifier}}
            </mat-cell> </ng-container> 
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Collected Date"> <mat-header-cell
                *matHeaderCellDef>Collected Date</mat-header-cell> <mat-cell
                *matCellDef="let station"> {{station.collectionDate}} </mat-cell> </ng-container> 
            <ng-container
                matColumnDef="No Stations ?"> <mat-header-cell
                *matHeaderCellDef>No Stations ?</mat-header-cell> <mat-cell
                *matCellDef="let station"> {{station.noIpStations}} </mat-cell> </ng-container> 
            <ng-container
                matColumnDef="No Smnp ?"> <mat-header-cell
                *matHeaderCellDef>No Smnp ?</mat-header-cell> <mat-cell
                *matCellDef="let station"> {{station.snmpFlagOn}} </mat-cell> </ng-container> 
            <ng-container
                matColumnDef="Export"> <mat-header-cell
                *matHeaderCellDef> Export </mat-header-cell> <mat-cell
                *matCellDef="let station">
            <button
                (click)="downloadCSV(station.productIdentifier,station.collectedData)">Export
                CSV</button>
            </mat-cell> </ng-container> 
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
            </mat-table>



            <mat-paginator *ngIf="sCollectionList" class="marginless-paginator-range-label"
                #paginator
                [pageIndex]="0"
                 [pageSize]="5"
                [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"> </mat-paginator>

        </div>
```

Following is the array response I receive, which is what I`m trying to display on UI:

```
[{
"productIdentifier":"365",
"snmpFlagOn":false,
"collectedData":"ahsgabbs s[lsnnspm] n",
"noIpStations":true,
"collectionDate":1511721000000
}]
```

Am I missing anything??

Comment: The question and issue is clear. But if you care about correct answer and you need it nearest time, please provide core example using `https://plnkr.co` - it helps to quickly test some parts without checking all code rows you provided.

Comment: As per what you said, and oddly enough for me, I tried to recreate a working example of the MatTable and Paginator in a seperate webeclipse project. It worked fine out there with paginator working perfectly fine. Still my original code is not working with paginator getting displayed in the UI, but not getting linked with the table as data comes from my server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular mat-table dataSource.paginator and dataSource.sort and dataSource.filter not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48943501/angular-mat-table-datasource-paginator-and-datasource-sort-and-datasource-filter)

Answer (score 8):

This is because of this.paginator is undefined at the time it going to assign to this.dataSource.paginator.

This is how i solve the problem

For Pagination

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false})
  set paginator(value: MatPaginator) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = value;
  }
```

For Sort

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false})
  set sort(value: MatSort) {
    this.dataSource.sort = value;
  }
```

As a side note im using Angular 9 at the movement.

Comment: Is this because {static: false} needs to be used when there is a dependency on  Structural Derivative?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: (Have a look at set timeout)

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange) {
    if (changes["dataSource"]) {
      this.data = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSource);
      setTimeout(() =>{
        this.data.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.data.sort = this.sort;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes this works!!  One thing to mention, you can just do `this.data.data` to update the data source instead of instantiating a new `MatTableDataSource` every time. Also, I was getting an "expression changed after change detection warning", so I also moved the `this.data.data` into the `setTimeout` and everything worked with no warning!

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the ngIf attribute from mat-paginator tag, I was also facing the same kind of issue while using it. But note that, your custom length value may not work when you again refresh your table for the second time or later.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when I tried to use the mat-table cdk with dynamic data from an api.

What worked for me was defining the paginator and sort right after assigning the table data within the getData function like this [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo2-d87oA9w):

In the component.ts

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

...

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
 }

 getData(){
    this.http.get<any>(this.dataUrl, {
      observe: 'response',
    }).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
          this.datasource.data = response.body;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
        });
      },
      error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.errorMessage = "Error retrieving Data!
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
      }
    });
  }
 }
```