# Angular mat-table dataSource.paginator and dataSource.sort and dataSource.filter not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material

**UPDATED: Changed the code to immediately call and assign the `dataSource`, but I still experience the same results, with the exception that the `sourceData.paginator` is working. The `sourceData.filter` and `sourceData.sort` is still not working.**

**PLEASE NOTE: I am getting no errors, as the error had to do with the paginator that is now working. Also, it might have to do with the format of my data, so included some data as an example. As a note, I use `response.data` for assigning my data to the source, and then use `{{asset.Data.FleetNumber}}` for displaying a field.**

I am quite new to Angular 5 and Angular Material. I am struggling with implementing the `mat-table` `dataSource` `paginator` and `sort` and `filterValue`.

**I get the following Error:** **(RESOLVED)**

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined

And my filter is not working. When I type in my filter field, after the 2nd character, my list returns empty.

I have tried different life-cycle hooks in an attempt to correctly assigning the `sort` and `paginator` to my `dataSource`, but it does not seem to work: `ngDoCheck()`, `ngAfterViewInit()`, `ngAfterViewChecked()`, `ngAfterContentInit()`. Obviously some of these cause an infinite loop.

**I have implemented my `dataSource` and `paginator` and `sort` and `filterValue` as follows in my component:**

```
...
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Asset>();
displayedColumns = ['fleetNumber', 'make'];

constructor(private assetDataService: AssetDataService, private router: Router,
    public dialog: MatDialog, public snackBar: MatSnackBar, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private toastr: ToastrService) {
    assetDataService.getAssetList().subscribe(results => {
      if (!results) { return };
      this.dataSource.data = results;
    });
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
}
...
```

**My view:**

```
<div class="asset-container">
  <div class="asset-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="fleetNumber">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fleet Number </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let asset"> {{asset.Data.FleetNumber}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Make Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="make">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Make </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let asset"> {{asset.Data.Make}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**Sample of data (one object in my array of objects returned. I use `response.data` for assigning my data to the source, and then use `{{asset.Data.FleetNumber}}` for displaying a field:**

```
[   {
      "Id":"5ee436a4-55ce-47b5-8489-82b190e7d489",
      "AssetType":"c00a71f5-d7f6-403b-b13f-37cf35961456",
      "AssetDetailId":"716ade20-871b-495b-9bb7-081d7cf1e57d",
      "Name":"Vehicle",
      "Description":"Vehicle Description",
      "TotalQuantity":1,
      "AssetDetail":{  
         "Id":"716ade20-871b-495b-9bb7-081d7cf1e57d",
         "Data":null,
         "Created":"2018-02-26T06:05:03.0695992Z",
         "CreatedById":null
      },
      "IncludeData":false,
      "Data":{  
         "Id":null,
         "FleetNumber":"FL002",
         "VehicleRegistrationNumber":"HFJ001GP",
         "LicenceNumber":"L1233465456",
         "VIN":"V5544257",
         "EngineNumber":"E4544564",
         "Make":"Porche",
         "Model":"911 Turbo",
         "Driven":true,
         "GVM":"2750kg",
         "TARE":"3250kg",
         "VehicleClass":"Class 1",
         "TitleHolder":"Mr T",
         "Owner":"T",
         "DateOfFirstRegister":"2018-01-31T22:00:00Z",
         "LicenceExpireDate":"2018-02-21T22:00:00Z",
         "IsComplete":true,
         "IsActive":true,
         "InsuranceCompany":"INS001",
         "PolicyNumber":"POL001",
         "InsuredValue":"R2500000.00",
         "FinanceHouse":"None",
         "FinanceContactNumber":"None",
         "FinanceStartDate":"2018-01-31T22:00:00Z",
         "FinanceEndDate":"2018-02-21T22:00:00Z",
         "MaintenanceSupplier":"None",
         "MaintenanceContactNumber":"123456",
         "MaintenanceStartDate":"2018-01-31T22:00:00Z",
         "MaintenanceEndDate":"2018-02-27T22:00:00Z",
         "Permits":[  
            {  
               "Permits":"Harbour Permit",
               "PermitTitle":"HB001",
               "PermitIssueDate":"2018-01-31T22:00:00Z",
               "PermitEndDate":"2018-02-16T22:00:00Z"
            },
            {  
               "AssetID":null,
               "Permits":"Cross-Border Permit",
               "PermitTitle":"C001",
               "PermitIssueDate":"2018-02-08T22:00:00Z",
               "PermitEndDate":"2018-02-22T22:00:00Z"
            }
         ],
         "VehicleTypeSpecificRegistration":"",
         "VehicleTypeSpecificRegistrationIssueDate":"",
         "VehicleTypeSpecificRegistrationEndDate":"",
         "PermitName":null,
         "PermitTitle":null
      },
      "Type":0,
      "Created":"2018-02-22T08:39:58.84",
      "CreatedById":""
    },
]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Pierre Mallet for the invested time in that detailed answer, that saved me tons of time. But as you can see inside the comments, i had problems to get the `this.dataSource.sort` and `this.dataSource.paginator` running.

After i posted my comment, i searched a bit and found out, that there is a problem with the `ViewChild` from Angular. The `ViewChild` doesn't catch anything with `*ngIf` in `ngAfterViewInit()`. So to get both running, you need to do the following:

Remove the following from `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

and add the following piece of code:

```
private paginator: MatPaginator;
  private sort: MatSort;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  setDataSourceAttributes() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    if (this.paginator && this.sort) {
      this.applyFilter('');
    }
  }
```

after that, everything should work like a charme. Source of my answer is this -> https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10205

many thanks to everyone who helped solving this issue!

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. I have the same issue, and this does not help at all. I can tell that the Paginator and Sort both know that they are attached to the data source, but the table appears to be unaware.

Comment: This worked well for me. Thanks so much. That viewChild structure essentially says 'when this exists in the UI, set the viewChild, and run this function'. Removes the need to wait for the UI to exists (with afterViewInit or a timeout). Works well with async piped data.

Comment: I had the same issue and I applied your solution! It works perfect for me (on Angular 8). Thanks!

Comment: It sorted my issue. Thanks bunch!

Answer (score 1):

As you data is asynchronous, you try to add the paginator before instantiating the dataSource.

So in order, you have to :

1/ instantiate the data source
2/ after view init "bind" the matSort and matPaginator
3/ when data assets are available, add them as the data of your source

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/njydaeokjxr) emulating the asynchronous getAssetList with an Observable.of().delay(XXX)

the main topic is :

```
  // 1/ create your instance of matTable
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(); 
  .......
  // 2/ call the xhr for getting asynchronous data and add it to matTable when available
  .......
  constructor (.....) {
    assetDataService.getAssetList().subscribe(results => {
        if (!results) { return };
        this.dataSource.data = results;
    });
  }
  .......
  // bind sorting, pagination and filtering
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

EDITED after data model example :

Your problem is that you cant make default sort/filtering works with nested data structure. The structure to be displayed should be flat and MatColumnDef should match the properties names to make filtering and sorting work out of the box.

So you have to flatten your data before using it in the DataTable

```
....
displayedColumns = ['fleetNumber', 'make'];
....
// on data resolve 
this.dataSource.data = data.map(item => ({
  fleetNumber: item.Data.FleetNumber,
  make: item.Data.Make
}));
```

then change the display in the template ( new data structure + lowerCamelCase matColumnDefs ) :

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="fleetNumber">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fleet Number </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let asset"> {{asset.fleetNumber}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Make Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="make">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Make </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let asset"> {{asset.make}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Here is the modified [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/njydaeokjxr)

Comment: Hey Pierre. Thanks for the info and feedback. That is exactly my implementation ;) *TARING_OUT_MY_HAIR*

Comment: no, it's not: in your implementation, you instantiate the MatTableDataSource after the return of the asynchronous data. Where in my implementation I instantiate it immediately, then populate the data when asynchronous data is returned.

Comment: my apologies! Did not see the call () . Thank you!

Comment: can you mark the answer as validated then? (for rep indeed :p and also for this question not to be marked as "unanswered". thx

Comment: will do, just have to implement it. was going to stop for the weekend....but you know how it is. ;)

Comment: Hey Pierre. I tried it that way round, and it still does not work. Only the paging works. The filter and sort does not work. I've no idea whether there is something I can add after `this.dataSource.sort` and `this.datSource.filter` to make it work. Anything I try adding to it, gives me an error.....

Comment: and what is the new error message? Can you update your code in your question no we can help you ?

Comment: Hey Pierre, I updated my code, as well as gave some sample data. I hope this helps. *fingers crossed*

Comment: Hey guys! I just found this question via google and i have exactly the same problem like onmyway - everything works fine but `this.dataSource.sort` and `this.dataSource.paginator` are not working. 

Filtering works when you correctly mapped your object to the dataSource - but i cant get sorting and pagination work - any tips? :/

Comment: @Sithys hard to tell without your code snippet, can you try to put an example on stackblitz ?

Comment: Look at my answer Pierre Mallet, i already solved it and posted the solution inside this topic :)

Comment: oh great, didnt notice your answer

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and the only thing that seemed to work for me, even after making sure I was using `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` was to use the following lines of code and set the data source after everything had loaded:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<T>(this.searchResults);
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<T>;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

  this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
}
```

Note that T indicates the Type of the data used in your table, so your MatTableDataSource and MatTable should have the same type. I hope this helps somebody else.